# MVVMLight and Windows 10

Tags: xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

Just about to try my hand at MVVM in a Universal Windows 10 app. To help I've been using the MVVMLight toolkit, and it works great in code. However, I wanted to try the EventToCommand in XAML to route an ItemClick on a list view to a command, but can't seem to reference the right library in the namespace.

I've tried `xmlns:MvvmLight="using:GalaSoft.MvvmLight"` but that doesn't seem to give me any EventToCommand intellisense. Is this feature supported for Windows 10 universal apps? If so, how do I use it in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this passage:

> Like mentioned above, there is no EventToCommand in the Windows 8.1
>   version of MVVM Light, and there will never be. This is because the
>   Blend team listened to my feedback and added the same capability to
>   their own InvokeCommandAction.

from [Using the EventArgsConverter in MVVM Light, and why is there no EventToCommand in the Windows 8.1 version?](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/) answers your question and provides the way forward...

Also check out this blog post [Building a Universal Application for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 with MVVM Light](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/04/building-a-universal-application-for-windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-8-1-with-mvvm-light/) in which Laurent Bugnion points to that same first blog post when answering the question about why there is no `EventToCommand` in MVVM Light for Universal.